# ansible can't find pycurl on OSX

Tags: python, macos, ansible

I'm just getting started with ansible, and I'm trying to get it to work with the `linode` module from OSX Yosemite. I'm using brew-installed Python, and pip-installed ansible. So I have done the following:

```
$ brew install python
$ PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss pip install pycurl
$ CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments pip install ansible
```

To test:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

$ python --version
Python 2.7.9

$ which ansible
/usr/local/bin/ansible

$ ansible --version
ansible 1.8.2
   configured module search path = None
```

When I run my playbook I get:

```
failed=True msg='pycurl required for this module'
```

So somehow ansible is not seeing the `pycurl` library.

Here is the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: "provision a server"
    local_action:
      module: linode
      api_key: FOO
      name: linode-test1
      plan: 1
      datacenter: 1
      distribution: 99
      password: 'superSecureRootPassword'
      ssh_pub_key: ssh-rsa FOO
      swap: 768
      wait: yes
      wait_timeout: 600
      state: present
```

Comment: Are you able to `import pycurl` from within python's interactive interpreter?

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. I built it with nss to get rid of some ssl warnings. When I import I get: >>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (none/other) is different from compile-time ssl backend (nss)

Comment: Hmm, just re-installed pycurl (without nss, which results in many warnings regarding SSL). I can now `import pycurl` successfully. Yet ansible still complains that it doesn't see it.

Comment: Can you compare the sys.path inside playbook (task: `shell: python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'`) and on command line?

Answer (score 1):

It's happening on ubuntu as well, finally figured out the solution. You need to explicity pass path to python executable

Change Ansible hosts file from

```
[local]
localhost
```

to

```
[local]
localhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python
```

or to your virtual environment python path.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 by editing `hosts`:

```
[local]
localhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python
```

You may then need additional Python dependencies:

```
pip install pycurl
pip install linode-python
```

Comment: First part is a verbatim copy of the solution from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43211501/2947502), second part has two subparts: one command is a copy of the command given in question. The other one (`pip install linode-python`) is a new piece of information.  However, the question clearly asks about solving `pycurl required for this module` problem and `linode-python` has no influence here. What's the point?

Comment: I had the same error as the questioner on first using the linode module; adding the path to python led to an error about not having pycurl; installing pycurl led to a further error about needing linode-python, so the "point" is I needed to install that as well and it might save someone else time. Could I have added a comment to the other answer? Perhaps, but it's a concise, legitimate and well intentioned answer.  Feel free to downvote.

Comment: I beg to differ in the assessment of the legitimacy. It's a copy of the OPs answer which you did not even bother to upvote, even though you claim it helped/would have helped you. I flagged it for moderation, and left a comment for others who will vote, because that's what I think I should have done, I don't need your permissions or suggestions.